# AWS Lambda function to read DynamoDB Table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to coding and writing a func to read data (i.e. scan table) from Dynamodb table. I am getting an error at step when we create DDB resource.

What am I missing here?

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        
        dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
        table = dynamodb.Table("TrackerTable")
        
        try:
            response = table.scan(
                FilterExpression=Attr('Id').eq('1745696') & Attr('Code').eq('LTA-121647')
            )
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        
        print("total count of element: ",len(response))
    }
```

Error message:

> errorMessage  "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax
> (lambda_function.py, line 7)" errorType   "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError"
> requestId "7333c030-1930-4396-ba84-07d7027482e1" stackTrace    0  "  File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 7\n            dynamodb =
> boto3.resource("dynamodb")\n"

Answer (score 2):

Your code is **invalid Python**. Not sure what you want to do, but you can't enclose everything with `return`. Maybe it should be:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table("TrackerTable")
    
    try:
        response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression=Attr('Id').eq('1745696') & Attr('Code').eq('LTA-121647')
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    
    print("total count of element: ",len(response))

    return json.dumps(response, default=str)
```